# Serving files uploaded by a user during development in django

Tags: django, static, media

This might be a dumb question but in the documentation it says:

> Serving files uploaded by a user during development.¶
>
> During development, you can serve user-uploaded media files from
>   MEDIA_ROOT using the `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()` view.
>
> This is not suitable for production use! For some common deployment
>   strategies, see Deploying static files.
>
> For example, if your MEDIA_URL is defined as /media/, you can do this
>   by adding the following snippet to your urls.py:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings 
> from django.conf.urls.static import static
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ... ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
> ```

Does that mean for production use `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` should not be used or should be used?

The way I understood this is that you shouldn't use `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()` but I'm not sure if that's not the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()` should not be used for deployment.

First, calling `views.serve()` anywhere will only work if `DEBUG = True`, and will raise an `Http404` if used when `DEBUG = False`, as should be the case when your app is deployed. The benefit of using this in development, however, is such that you don't have to run [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)/gather your static files: you can pull them from your static or media root without having to move things around.

It's also somewhat insecure: `views.serve()` will guess the content type of the the file its serving using the [`mimetype`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#module-mimetypes) module, which will rely on the map files for the platform you're developing on: the behavior might not be the same in production because of the mimetype module in your specific environment.

The docs have more on [`django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve).

Now when it comes to production, serving static/media files isn't something that Django's WSGI will do well for you. Django is written to serve application content, and won't perform as well when it comes to serving static/user uploaded content. If you're expecting even medium load, using a separate server such as [Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) or [Nginx](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) in conjunction with a web server like [uWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/) is far more sustainable and can handle more. [This doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/) details more on how to set those up/explains more.

Answer (score 2):

In production, you should have `Debug = False`. When you do that, static files are no longer served by Django.

A popular substitute is using Amazon's S3 Buckets. For example purposes, let's say you create a new bucket. Your `MEDIA_URL` would look something like:

`MEDIA_URL = 'bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media'`

You would serve static files the same way.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so, thanks ! I think i'll just have to go through that process once